# error when I call procedure in mysql:Error Code: 1222. The used SELECT statements have a different number of columns

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

```
delimiter /
drop procedure if exists piez_vend;/
create procedure piez_vend (IN _piez varchar(20), out nvend int(11))
begin
SELECT numpieza, count(numvend) into nvend from preciosum where numpieza like _piez;
end
/
delimiter ;

call piez_vend('dd-0001-210',@nvend);
```

Sample data

```
 numpieza, numvend, preciounit, diassum, descuento
'a-1001-l', '1', '1.60', '3', '0'
'a-1001-l', '3', '3.00', '1', '0'
'c-400-z', '1', '7.80', '4', '5'
'c-400-z', '6', '6.50', '3', '0'
'dd-0001-210', '1', '300.00', '3', '15'
'dd-0001-210', '2', '310.00', '5', '12'
'dd-0001-210', '4', '287.00', '15', '10'
'm-0001-c', '1', '550.00', '3', '10'
'm-0001-c', '5', '570.00', '7', '15'
't-0002-at', '2', '25.80', '3', '0'
't-0002-at', '4', '27.00', '5', '7'
```

Comment: What happens if there are multiple rows where `numpieza` is similar to `_piez`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message is a little obtuse.

> The used SELECT statements have a different number of columns

It means this query

```
SELECT numpieza, count(numvend) into nvend from preci...
```

doesn't work because the `SELECT` mentions two columns. But you're using `into` to tell MySQL where to put the value of only one of the columns. It doesn't know what to do with the other column.  Try this instead.

```
SELECT count(numvend) into nvend from preci...
```

**Pro tip** Stored procedures are tricky to debug. It's helpful to try the queries in them before you wrap them in the procedure.